# inherit mutiple code files in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Can I Inherit multiple code files in ASP.NET ?? either all are C# or one is C# and other are VB ??

Is there any possibility to make use of 2 programming languages like C# and VB.NET or other in a single ASP.NET page?

I heard we can work on both PHP and ASP.NET together on same page how come its true??...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within a single ASP.NET (aspx) file it is possible to use two seperate languages using the following syntax

```
<script language=c# runat=server> 
...
</script>

<script language=vb runat=server> 
...
</script>
```

The real question is why would you want to do something like this, it would make your code impossible to maintain

Answer (score 1):

you can use C# and vb files in one project, but you cannot use 2 languages in one page (in code behind).
To integrate PHP with ASP.NET - read this question: [Best way to integrate PHP with asp.net / asp.net-mvc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1385864/best-way-to-integrate-php-with-asp-net-asp-net-mvc)

Answer (score 0):

You can only inherit multiple code files if they are part of the same inheritance hierarchy - remember a page is just a class, so all the normal inheritance rules apply.